# JIRA Rest API select minimal resource

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am using JIRA REST API for querying issues with below jql

```
jql=project =SLUB and "Agile Team" in ("Iris (B2C)")&fieldsByKeys=true&fields=status&maxResults=1
```

I am getting api response as

```
{
  "expand": "names,schema",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 1,
  "total": 1172,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "35988",
      "self": "https://xyz.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/35988",
      "key": "SLUB-7071",
      "fields": {
        "status": {
          "self": "https://xyz.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10200",
          "description": "",
          "iconUrl": "https://xyz.atlassian.net/",
          "name": "To Do",
          "id": "10200",
          "statusCategory": {
            "self": "https://xyz.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
            "id": 2,
            "key": "new",
            "colorName": "blue-gray",
            "name": "To Do"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I only fetch status name instead of complete status resource. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e3181
Check This .

The fields param (which can be specified multiple times) gives a comma-separated list of fields to include in the response. This can be used to retrieve a subset of fields. A particular field can be excluded by prefixing it with a minus.

By default, only navigable (*navigable) fields are returned in this search resource. Note: the default is different in the get-issue resource -- the default there all fields (*all).

- *all - include all fields
- *navigable - include just navigable fields summary,comment - include just the summary and comments
- -description - include navigable fields except the description (the default is *navigable for search)
- *all,-comment - include everything except comments

Copied From [Here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/232937/api-jql-search-results-provide-way-too-much-information).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got this answer from JIRA support team. "
It is not possible to only return the name of the status. The suggestion provided by the reply is more to retrieve fields, not so much on getting the specific JSON tag. You have already used the field parameter to return only the status field details but further thinning down to only get the name of the status is not possible."

Comment: So if I want to get all in Java how do I write it? In the Jira documentation, there is written that it is a type of Array<string>.